# Microphone is picking up audio but not in meeting apps like Webex or Zoom

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, zoom-meeting, webex

An All in One with onboard mic array and camera is able to pick up audio fine when testing it using things like Windows Voice Recorder, or an online test (I use https://www.onlinemictest.com/), but unable to capture audio when a meeting starts in apps like Zoom or Cisco Webex.

The mic pickup levels do bounce around when talking in the windows sound control panel under the recording tab.

Things I've tried:

- I turned off all audio enhancements
- Installing the latest drivers and previous ones.
- Toggling Mic capture in BIOS
- I made sure that these apps had permission to use the microphone in the privacy settings for windows.
- Reinstalling the apps with the latest versions.

To note, these programs are able to detect the devices in their respective sound settings and able to pick up audio levels (you can see the mic levels bouncing around while talking in the tests before the meeting starts) but I'm not able to get audio to record when the meetings are started.

At this point, I'm not sure what else I can do.

The computer is a Dell Optiplex 7460, standalone - no secondary monitor or headphones/external camera connected.

Comment: I suggest you try an external microphone. Install it, make it default and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: zoom has a test audio functionality - what does it say? see if correct audio input is selected.

Comment: Is the problem only with capturing - can the others hear you? How are you capturing the meetings?

Comment: I'm sorry, when I say capture audio, I mean the other meeting participants aren't able to hear.

Answer (score 0):

Apps like Skype and Zoom have internal mic settings that you need to be aware of. Check the settings on the App to make sure that the app is using the desired input audio source.

Additionally, some of these apps will lower the volume settings when opened, check the volume levels in the windows settings to ensure they weren't lowered.

///// Trouble shooting
In broadcasting, we like to hear ourselves on the Mic so we know it's working, try turning on "listen to the device" on the Mic to ensure the mic is working.

Open sounds and select the recording tab, right-click mic you want to and open properties select the listen Tab and turn on the Listen to this device select the desired output(Best to wear headphone when doing so to avoid feedback). Hit apply. Does the Mic work?

Comment: The input is set to my Realtek mic array. Windows, for some reason has "sterio mix" as a disabled input device. I enabled that and tried that as input instead but it was the same result. Tried the sterio mix for both programs as the input source.

Comment: Stereo mix is disabled by default, it's used for recording the output audio of the computer. Years ago the music industry wasn't a big fan of people being able to record music that was playing off their computer so started paying off some of the computer companies to disable it. You don't want to use that as recording device if you are trying to use the Mic.